# What are those berry-like plants in this photo?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I found this photo on a Flickr gallery and I have no idea what this plant is. Is it supposedly a type of berry or something?

[image]

Comment: I really think you should be giving full attribution to the owner of the flickr photo or gallery. Or at least a link to the source.

Comment: A google image search finds:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/15110103@N08/2044059567
which was taken in The Hague, Netherlands. And also identifies the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the geography of where the photo was taken, we could guess this is a European Mountain Ash (Sorbus aucuparia) which is fairly widespread in North America and Europe (but doesn't really grow in South America, Asia, Africa, Australia)..

You can look up this plant for information on the berries. They contain vitamin C, but don't have much other desirable properties.

Comment: There was no exact location on the Flickr page, so I couldn’t put the date.

Comment: @Kylethedownvotedisliker definitely an _Sorbus_ tree, sometimes known as Rowan or Whitebeam. Pinnate leaves with serrations, red pome-like fruit in corymbs, very distinctive.